# Searching a domain for workstation specific user is logged in

Tags: c#, search, active-directory

I am trying to write a little application which will search the domain for the workstation a user is logged in on and return the host name/ip of the workstation.

So far all I have is the username stored in a string.

I am using VS Express for Desktop so I do not have access to a lot of references like web.

I am pretty new to C# but I should be able to understand most things.

Thanks!

Prototype:

```
public string get_comp(string user)
```

Comment: I doubt that this is even an intrinsic active directory feature. The simplest way would be to set up a group policy with a login script that will log the logins to some sort of system (database?), which you will then query for data.

Comment: The problem is I dont have access to that, I dont have direct access to the scripts themselfs. What I was thinking is searching the domain for computers and check each computer for the logged on user, if it matches the searched user then it's a hit if not keeps searching.